# If I write an option contract, sell it and then buy it back, will it still be an open interest?

Tags: options

If the original writer of an option contract buys it back, does that mean a reduction in the open interest?

To my understanding, option contracts are written and then sold/traded/bought back. The trading volume and open interest can be tracked.

If a large amount of unexpired out-of-the-money options contracts "disappear" (e.g. from one day to another the number of open interest goes from 2k to 0), what can be the case? Does that mean that someone just exercised their out-of-the-money options contracts or can the original writer buy it back and "de-write" or invalidate the options, resulting in an open interest of zero?

Comment: why would you buy back an option contract that's out-of-the-money for the holder?

Comment: you would buy back an OTM contract because you no longer wish to be obligated to the terms of the contract.  A common example is a covered call writer who would prefer  to keep his stock.  As the stock approaches the short strike, the contract is bought to close (BTC). It is preferable to do so before the contract becomes ITM.  Sometimes this is part of a roll which means BTC the existing contract and sell to open a higher strike and possibly a later expiration.

Answer (score 1):

Open Interest  represents the number of contracts that exist on any given day. Each party to an option trade may be opening or closing the contract. There are 4 scenarios:

Buy to Open (BTO) and Sell To Open (STO)

- Both parties are initiating a new position (one new buyer and one new seller) so Open Interest increases by one

Buy to Open (BTO) and Sell To Close (STC)

- If a contract owner sells to a new trader, Open Interest does not change (an existing contract is changing hands)

Buy To Close (BTC) and Sell to Open (STO)

- If someone short a contract buys from a new writer, Open Interest does not change (an existing contract is changing hands)

Buy To Close (BTC) and Sell  to Close (STC)

- Both parties are closing an existing position (one previous buyer and one previous seller) so Open Interest declines by one

If Open Interest is declining then there are two possible causes:

1. Both parties are closing their contract (BTC or STC)
2. Contracts are being exercised.  Note that these would be in-the-money contracts (ITM) not out-of-the-money (OTM) because it makes no sense to exercise to buy or sell at a worse price than what is available in the market.

Comment: Do all these situations contribute to volumes? Including closing contracts and exercising contracts? Do they all add 1 to volumes?

Comment: Each one of these 4 situations results in a volume increase of one.  Exercise has no effect on volume but reduces open interest by one (the contract no longer exists).

Comment: If I understood well in the "Buy To Close (BTC) and Sell to Open (STO)" scanario, a contract is not really changing hand but instead an old contract is being closed and a new one is being opened so in the end the open interest count does not change.

Comment: Not exactly.  On day one, (-A) sells to open and (+B) buys to open.  One contract exists with (-A) and (+B) as counterparties.  At a later time, (+A) buys to close and (-C) sells to open.  Yes, (+A) is closing an existing position and (-C) is opening a new position but in terms of contracts, (-C) has replaced (-A) as the counterparty to (+B).  An old contract does not  cease to exist. A new contract is not created.  The same contract is still in existence but the counterparty to (+B) has changed.  (-A) and (+B) became (-C) and (+B). The short holder of the contract just changed.

Comment: In the end it's exactly the same thing but the second scenario (BTO + STC) looks more like something (a contract) is changing ownership while for the third scenario (BTC + STO) a metaphor of a contract being closed and a new one being opened looks more intuitive, at least to me :)

Comment: **...a contract is not really changing hand but instead an old contract is being closed and a new one is being opened so in the end the open interest count does not change.**  You are  confusing  a new position with a new contract. The EXISTING CONTRACT is  changing hands when one of the counterparties changes and there are two possibilities for this --->   BTO + STC or STO + BTC.

Answer (score 0):

First there is no transparent way to track if he bought an "original" or "not-original" option contact back.

Second, the option that he bought (back) might or might not be newly written by a new writer.

Thus, the answer is indeterminate.